# Magento 2 : Make 'Apply Coupon Code' Required Field in Admin Order Creation

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, backend, coupon

I have Magento 2.1.6.

I need to make 'Apply Coupon Code' a required field in admin (only) order creation for specific customer group.

Top marks if anyone can work this out as I am stumped.

[image]